# extract only the function name(string values) using a single regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract function names from a javascript file using regex.
The 2 cases are
**Case 1:**

```
{ 'test1': function(){},
  'test2': function(){}
}
```

**Case 2:**

```
{ test1: function(){}
  test2: function(){}
}
```

Expected result for either case : [test1, test2]

Now when i use this regex expression with this  javascript code

```
contents.match(/(.+)(?=: function\()/g);
```

The current result i get is

```
[ '\t\'test1\'',
    '\t\'test2\'']
```

How i get the expected result : [test1, test2] , without including special characters like \t \'

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps use a capturing group with a backreference to group 1and capture the data that you want in group 2 https://regex101.com/r/n5HI10/1 `('?)([^'\s{}]+)\1: function\(\)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

capture any string (not a blank space, nor a `'` or `"`) when it may be followed by `'` or `"`, any whitespace, and `: function`

```js
let contents = `
{ test1:function(){}
  'test2' : function(){}
  "tes-t2": function(){}
  "teè#//st2"   : function(){}
}
`
console.log(contents.match(/([^'"\s]+)(?=['"]?\s*:\s*function\()/g))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of 2 capturing groups.

In group 1 match either `'` or `"` and use a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) `\1` to match the same as what is matched in group 1 to prevent function names to start and end with a different quote like `'test1"`

In group 2 capture the function name.

```
(["']?)([^"'\s{}]+)\1\s*:\s*function\(\)
```

In parts

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `["']?` Match an optional `'` or `"`
- `)` Close group
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^'"\s{}]+` Match 1+ times any char other than the listed using a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `)\1` Close group 2
- `\s*:\s*` Match `:` between 0+ whitespace chars
- `function\(\)` Match function()

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yexJWs/1)

```js
const regex = /(["']?)([^"'\s{}]+)\1\s*:\s*function\(\)/gm;
const str = `{ 'test1': function(){},
  'test2': function(){}
}

{ test1: function(){}
  test2: function(){}
}
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[2]);
}
```